How to set debug environment variables for ASP.NET Web API project on .NET 4.8?
I am building an ASP.NET Web API project on .NET 4.8 and also deploying it to Azure. I use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable to get variable values. In Azure, this is easy to configure because they have a settings editor in the Azure web app settings page.
But when I test locally, how can I set some values in Visual Studio so I can read them when debugging?
I read online that you can go to Project > Properties > Debug tab but this is only available on desktop and console apps.

If you want to retrieve value using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable, then store the key-values in System Properties => EnvironmentVariable and retrieve value with                            string Val = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SampleKey", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User); 

If you want to store them at project level, then set it at Properties => Settings and retrieve using string key = Properties.Settings.Default.Test;

You can set the Environment Variables in many ways.

If you want to retrieve the values using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable , then you need to set the values in System Properties => Environment Variables.


Retrieve the value using,
string Va1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SampleKey");

OR
string Val = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SampleKey", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);


But these values can be accessed by any Application within the System.

If you want to set the variables for App level, then you can set them directly in the code using


Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FromCode", "Value from Code");

OR

Can set them in the web.config => appsettings and retrieve them using ConfigurationManager and then set it back to Environment Variable in code.

web.config file:
<appSettings>
  <add key="FromConfigFile" value="Value Strored in Config File" />
</appSettings>

Retrieve in Code:
 string FromConfigFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromConfigFile"];
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FromCode", FromConfigFile);
 string valfromconfig = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FromCode");

Output:


Project > Properties > Debug tab but this is only available on desktop and console apps.


In .NET Framework, you have option to set the values in Properties under Settings tab as settings.



Retrieve using the line of below code,

string sampleval = Properties.Settings.Default.SampleVal;


@omega - Is your issue resolved ?
